# Sharepoint cannot see newly deployed features and will not activate them

Tags: c#, sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

I've been updating a SP2010 solution which integrates an external content source into search via BCS. This solution deploys a feature (featureA) to the farm scope. I split it into two features, one (FeatureA) deploying to the farm scope, and one (featureB) to the site scope.

My update script does this:

- Deactivate FeatureA on the farm
- Update-SPSolution  with the new wsp file (same name)
- Activate FeatureA on the farm
- Activate FeatureB on the two sites (on two different web apps)

The script bombs on the last two steps, saying

```
Enable-SPFeature : The Feature is either not found or not a Farm Level Feature. Use Url parameter to specify the scope of the Feature.
```

for the first one (farm), and

```
Enable-SPFeature : The Feature is not a Farm Level Feature and is not found in a Site level defined by the Url http://url-site
```

on the second one (sites)

This is a test run on the CI server, which means it will also crash on the production server.
However, deploying the package on my machine, and activating the features, works fine.

I've checked, the features are actually present in the SharePoint folder, so the deployment seems to have gone ok. I can't work out why SharePoint can't see them though. If I run Get-SPFeature, they are not in the list.

I've tried iisreset, to no avail.

EDIT:

I've managed to get SharePojnt to notice the two features, by using Install-SPFeature.
However, it still won't enable FeatureB, but errors out with:

```
Enable-SPFeature : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
```

I'm at a bit of a loss once again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `Update-SPSolution` when new files have been added to the solution package.

From [Update-SPSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607724.aspx):

> The Update-SPSolution cmdlet upgrades a deployed SharePoint solution in the farm. Use this cmdlet only if a new solution contains the same set of files and features as the deployed solution. If files and features are different, the solution must be retracted and redeployed by using the Uninstall-SPSolution and Install-SPSolution cmdlets, respectively.

For more information, see [Adding Features during Solution Update](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/adding-features-during-solution-update)

Comment: asked in 2011 .. answered in 2012 .. and helped me in 2013 , Thank you :)